# add(CarouselLoadEvent) was called without a registered event handler. Make sure to register a handler via on<CarouselLoadEvent>((event, emit) {...})

Tags: flutter

```
// ignore_for_file: override_on_non_overriding_member, depend_on_referenced_packages

import 'package:blabbly/src/domain/entities/movie_entity.dart';
import 'package:blabbly/src/domain/entities/no_params.dart';
import 'package:blabbly/src/domain/usecases/get_trending.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'movie_carousel_event.dart';
part 'movie_carousel_state.dart';

class MovieCarouselBloc extends Bloc<MovieCarouselEvent, MovieCarouselState> {
  final GetTrending getTrending;

  MovieCarouselBloc({
    required this.getTrending,
  }) : super(MovieCarouselInitial());

  @override
  Stream<MovieCarouselState> mapEventToState(
    MovieCarouselEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is CarouselLoadEvent) {
      final moviesEither = await getTrending(NoParams());
      yield moviesEither.fold(
        (l) => MovieCarouselError(),
        (movies) {
          return MovieCarouselLoaded(
            movies: movies,
            defaultIndex: event.defaultIndex,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Error :
The following StateError was thrown building Builder:
Bad state: add(CarouselLoadEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})

Friends, I get such an error. What is the solution to the error? I would be very happy if you show it on my codes.

Comment: What bloc version are you using?